# Pinata IPFS's pinFileToIPFS method not accepting a user uploaded file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern, ipfs

I am working on a project (using React.js Express.js and Node.js) to convert a user uploaded image into and NFT on Ethereum blockchain and for that, I need to upload the image on an IPFS (I am using Pinata) and then use the pinata URI in the metadata to mint a new NFT. (Do let me know if I am wrong here, I am still newbie to web3)

For uploading my image onto the Pinata IPFS, I am sending the base64 string of the image from the client side to the server side and then calling the `pinFileToIPFS` method. This is the code of my server side file

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const router = require('express').Router();
const { Readable } = require('stream');

const pinFileToIPFS = (image) => {
    const url = `https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinJSONToIPFS`;
    const buffer = Buffer.from(image);
    const stream = Readable.from(buffer);
    const filename = `an-awesome-nft_${Date.now()}.png`;
    stream.path = filename;

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", stream);

return axios.post(url,
        formData,
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary= ${formData._boundary}`,
                'pinata_api_key': "*******************",
                'pinata_secret_api_key': "**********************************",
            }
        }
    ).then(function (response) {
        console.log("Success: ", response);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Fail! ", error.response.data);
    });
};

router.route('/').post((req, res) => {
    const image = req.body.image;
    pinFileToIPFS(image);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here `req.body.image` contains the base64 string of the user uploaded file.
I have tried to convert the base64 string into a buffer and then convert the buffer into a readable stream (as done in the official Pianata documentation but for a localy file) and then wrap it up in FormData(), but I keep getting the following error.

```
data: {
  error: 'This API endpoint requires valid JSON, and a JSON content-type'
}
```

I know the problem is with the format my image/file is being sent to the API but I can't figure out. I am still a newbie to web3 and blockchains so please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way of interacting with Pinata, is by using their [Node.JS SDK](https://docs.pinata.cloud/pinata-node-sdk). This SDK has a `pinFileToIPFS` function, allows you to upload an image to their IPFS nodes in the form of a readableStream.
A sample of this would look like

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readableStreamForFile = fs.createReadStream('./yourfile.png');
const options = {
    pinataMetadata: {
        name: MyCustomName,
        keyvalues: {
            customKey: 'customValue',
            customKey2: 'customValue2'
        }
    },
    pinataOptions: {
        cidVersion: 0
    }
};
pinata.pinFileToIPFS(readableStreamForFile, options).then((result) => {
    //handle results here
    console.log(result);
}).catch((err) => {
    //handle error here
    console.log(err);
});
```

**However**, if you are deadset on using their API endpoints and simply posting to them via axios, there is a [seperate API endpoint](https://docs.pinata.cloud/api-pinning/pin-file). `/pinning/pinFileToIPFS`. Examples of this method can be found in their [API Docs](https://docs.pinata.cloud/api-pinning/pin-file).

Answer (score 1):

When you are uploading an image or file to Pinata IPFS with node js. These are the steps that even don't need Pinata Node.js SDK.

**1- You can upload an image from the front end with React or Next.js. Code is given below.**

```js
const uploadAttachment = async (data, token) => {
  try {
    return await Api.post(`${ApiRoutes.upload_attachment}`, data, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token, //the token is a variable which holds the token
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      status: 404,
    };
  }
};

export default uploadAttachment;
```

**2- You need to install multer to upload an image.**

```js
const multer = require("multer");
global.uploadSingleFile = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });
```

**3- Set up your route with multer middleware and action which you are going to call.**

```js
 .post(
    "/attachments/upload",
    uploadSingleFile.single("file"),
    actions.attachments.upload.pinFileToIPFSLocal
  );
```

**4- Last step where you will hit the Pinata endpoint with Pinata API & Secret key.**

```js
pinFileToIPFSLocal: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const url = "https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS";
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", JSON.stringify(req.file), req.file.originalname);

      axios
        .post(url, formData, {
          maxContentLength: -1,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`,
            pinata_api_key: process.env.PINATA_API_KEY,
            pinata_secret_api_key: process.env.PINATA_API_SECRET,
            path: "somename",
          },
        })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("Result...", data);
          return utils.response.response(
            res,
            "Upload image to ipfs.",
            true,
            200,
            data.data
          );
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return utils.response.response(
            res,
            "Image not upload to ipfs",
            false,
            200,
            err
          );
        });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be an error on the image parameter. A simple buffer representation of the image should work. The readable stream is not necessary.

Instead of creating the buffer, you could use middleware like [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) to access the buffer representation of the file uploaded on the client-side directly.

```
  const file = req.files;
  const url = "https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS";
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append("file", file.file.data, { filepath: "anyname" });
  const result = await axios.post(url, data, {
    maxContentLength: -1,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
      pinata_api_key: process.env.PINATA_API_KEY,
      pinata_secret_api_key: process.env.PINATA_API_SECRET,
      path: "somename",
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider changing the following two lines and using the `https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS` endpoint instead:

`const buffer = Buffer.from(image);` -> `const buffer = Buffer.from(image, "base64");`

and

`formData.append("file", stream);` -> `formData.append("file", stream, "fileNameOfChoiche.png);`

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. You are using url that used for json file upload. this is the url you should use to upload image

```
  const url = `https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS`;
```

- you don't have to convert buffer to a readable stream.
- I am not sure if this is correct `${formData._boundary}`. should be

  ```
  "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data: boundary=${formData.getBoundary()}`,
  ```